# Dynamic programming problems solution to interleaving strings

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem, and I gave up, and found the solution below, although I do not understand how the solution works, or why it works. Any in-depth solution would be deeply appreciated.

Question:

> Given `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, find whether `s3` is formed by the interleaving of `s1`
>   and `s2`.
>
> For example, Given:
>
> ```
> s1 = "aabcc"
> s2 = "dbbca"
> ```
>
> - When `s3 = "aadbbcbcac"`, return true.
> - When `s3 = "aadbbbaccc"`, return false.

Solution:

```
  public static boolean isInterleave(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        if (s3.length() == 0 && s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() == 0)
            return true;

        else if (s3.length() != s1.length() + s2.length())
            return false;
        boolean isInter[][] = new boolean[s1.length()+1][s2.length()+1];
        isInter[0][0] = true;
        for ( int i = 1; i <= s1.length(); ++i){
            if (s1.charAt(i-1) == s3.charAt(i-1))
                isInter[i][0] = true;
            else
                break;
        }
        for ( int i = 1; i <= s2.length(); ++i){
            if (s2.charAt(i-1) == s3.charAt(i-1))
                isInter[0][i] = true;
            else
                break;
        }
        // DP
        for ( int i = 1; i <= s1.length(); ++i){
            for ( int j = 1; j <= s2.length(); ++j){
                if (s3.charAt(i+j-1) == s1.charAt(i-1))
                    isInter[i][j] = isInter[i-1][j] || isInter[i][j];
                if (s3.charAt(i+j-1) == s2.charAt(j-1))
                    isInter[i][j] = isInter[i][j-1] || isInter[i][j];
            }
        }
        return isInter[s1.length()][s2.length()];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Python slice syntax here because it is nice. `S[:-1]` means the string `S` with its last character removed and `S[:n]` means the prefix of `S` that has length `n`.

The key idea is that if `C` is an interleaving of `A` and `B`, then `C[:-1]` is either an interleaving of `A` and `B[:-1]` or of `A[:-1]` and `B`. On the other hand, if `C` is an interleaving of `A` and `B`, then `C + 'X'` is an interleaving of `A + 'X'` and `B` and it is also an interleaving of `A` and `B + 'X'`.

These are the substructure properties we need to apply dynamic programming.

We define `f(i, j) = true`, if `s1[:i]` and `s2[:j]` can be interleaved to form `s3[:(i+j)]` and `f(i,j) = false` otherwise. By the observation above we have

```
f(0,0) = true
f(i,0) = f(i-1, 0) if s3[i-1] == s1[i-1]
f(0,j) = f(0, j-1) if s3[j-1] == s2[j-1]
f(i,j) = true if s3[i+j-1] = s1[i-1] and f(i-1, j)
f(i,j) = true if s3[i+j-1] = s2[j-1] and f(i, j-1)
```

In all the other cases we have `f(i,j) = false`.
The Java code just implements this recurrence using dynamic programming. That said, I would implement it in a bit more concise way:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); ++j)
        isInter[i][j] = (i == 0 && j == 0)
           || (i > 0 && s1.charAt(i-1) == s3.charAt(i+j-1) && isInter[i-1][j])
           || (j > 0 && s2.charAt(j-1) == s3.charAt(i+j-1) && isInter[i][j-1]);
```

Comment: Hi, can you change your answer to support Java; I don't understand Python string alteration syntax.

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan: You can translate it yourself if you need to: As I mentioned, `A[:n] = A.substring(0,n)` and `A[:-1] = A.substring(0,A.length-1)`. I thought the main problem you were having was on a conceptional level, so pseudocode should be fine to help your understanding

Comment: How do I improve my understanding of DP problems, mind sharing what you did to so quickly pick up what the problem was doing? Please refer me to some resources/books so I can be as strong as you

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan Unfortunately there is no single trick that magically makes you solve problems a lot faster. But it helps to understand the theory behind DP (optimal substructure property). It also helps to think in recursion rather than iteration. With the basic knowledge acquired, thinking about problems (practice!) is the best way to learn. There's platforms like TopCoder and Codeforces that have tons of material. [TopCoder tutorials](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index&module=Static) are actually somewhat useful in learning the basics (there's an article about DP as well).

Comment: I know this is a somewhat vague question, but your ability to grasp the problem impresed me, and I was curious as to what you've done to practice or has it just been TopCoder and codeforces? Maybe I thought a book would have great examples, etc.

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan Oh and for this problem in particular, the well-known algorithms to solve [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) and Levenshtein distance use the very same technique. Familiarity with a lot of different algorithms and problems definitely helps. Not sure about books, I usually learn stuff by looking at code and research material. I heard Knuth's books and Cormen are quite good though. And yes, competitive programming teaches you a *lot* about algorithms

Comment: Thank you very much; Ich schätze Ihre Hilfe

Answer (score 3):

The first few lines just deal with simple cases that can be resolved based only on the input string lengths. These tests simplify the remaining code by allowing it to assume that the lengths match.

The guts of the algorithm calculate an array `isInter`, where `isInter[i][j]` is true after iteration `(i,j)` if, and only if, the first `i+j` characters of `s3` can be formed by interleaving the first `i` characters of `s1` with the first `j` characters of `s2`.

`isInter[i][0]` is true if, and only if, the first `i` characters of `s3` match the first `i` characters of `s1`. Similarly, `isInter[0][i]` is true if, and only if, the first `i` characters of `s3` match the first `i` characters of `s2`.

The final loop builds up the remaining elements of isInter using already calculated elements and matches between the next character of `s3` and either the next character of `s1` or the next character of `s2`.

After `isInter` has been completely calculated, `isInter[s1.length()][s2.length()]` is true if, and only if, the whole of `s3` can be formed by interleaving the whole of `s1` with the whole of `s2`.

Comment: I think this reveals a bug in the code -- `if (s1.charAt(i-1) == s3.charAt(i-1))` should be `if (s1.charAt(i-1) == s3.charAt(i-1) && isInter[i-1][0])`, and likewise for the second base-case loop.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I thought the `break` statement effectively implements that rule. All elements of isInter are initially `false`.

Comment: Ah, so it does -- the bug was in me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt to show how the code works, using extremely plain syntax in C++. Their are some inline comments in the code for you to understand. It can't get simpler than this :)

```
//using dynamic programming : O(n^2)
bool is_interleaved_On2_DP(string s1, string s2, string s3)
    {
    bool ret = false;
    int len1 = s1.length();
    int len2 = s2.length();
    int len3 = s3.length();

    if( len1 + len2 != len3 )
        {
        return ret;
        }

#define M(i, j) match[ (i) * len1 + (j) ]

    //bool match[len1 + 1][len2 + 1]; //todo; use dynamic allocation
    bool* match = new bool[ (len1+1)*(len2+1) ];
    int i, j, k;

    /* init match table to be all false */
    for( i = 0; i <= len1; i++ )
        {
        for( j = 0; j <= len2; j++ )
            {
            M(i, j) = false;
            }
        }

    /* init match[0][0] == true */
    M(0, 0) = true; //why ? null is interleaving 2 other nulls :)

    /* init the s1 side of table i.e. column */
    for( i = 1; i <= len1; i++ )
        {
        char c1 = s1[i - 1];
        char c3 = s3[i - 1];
        if(c1 == c3)
            {
            M(i, 0) = true;
            }
        else
            {
            break;
            }
        }

    /* init the s2 side of table i.e. row */
    for( j = 1; j <= len2; j++ )
        {
        char c2 = s2[j - 1];
        char c3 = s3[j - 1];
        if(c2 == c3)
            {
            M(0, j) = true;
            }
        else
            {
            break;
            }
        }

    /* compute remaining table */
    for( i = 1; i <= len1; i++ )
        {
        char c1 = s1[i - 1];
        for( j = 1; j <= len2; j++ )
            {
            char c2 = s2[j - 1];
            int k = i + j; //index for s3
            char c3 = s3[k - 1];

            if(c1 == c3)
                {
                M(i, j) = M(i - 1, j) || M(i, j);
                }

            if(c2 == c3)
                {
                M(i, j) = M(i, j - 1) || M(i, j);
                }
            }
        }

    ret = M(len1, len2);

    delete [] match;
#undef M
    return ret;
    }
```